# How can I add a element everytime after 4 elements in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm immigrating my code to Vue.js so pretty new to Vue. As you see the screenshot(link below), There are 4 columns inside div with `columns` class name. I was trying to use v-if to add the div(class `columns`) conditionally but I have no idea how to get a length of columns elements in Vue.

[image: This is What I'm trying to make]

**Example Code**

```
<template lang="pug">
.container
  .columns(v-if="") // add this conditionally
    .column.is-3.vid(v-for='item in items')
      .panel
        p.is-marginless
         a(href=item.videoId)
           img(src=item.thumbnail)
        .panel.vidInfo
          .columns.hax-text-centered
            .column
              .panel-item.reddit-ups
                | item.score
                i.fa.fa-reddit-alien.fa-2x
              .panel-item.reddit-date
                i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-2x
</template>
```

Comment: `v-if="items.length === <whatever>"`?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal That'd work only one time. There's no v-for loop out of the v-if loop

Comment: You want the `.columns` to be added if `items.length ===` some specific number or ?

Comment: So many similar questions like this on SO today. I'll ask the same question; What reason do you have for splitting the items into separate containers? You may be able to use CSS to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Phil I'm using bulma css framework so I'm just following the guideline!

Comment: @Phil How do you implement this using CSS? I want to know about it

Answer (score 0):

You can access v-for iteration number like this:

change

```
 .column.is-3.vid(v-for='item in items')
```

to

```
.column.is-3.vid(v-for='(item, index) in items')
```

then somewhere where you need it check the index:

```
v-if="(index % 4 === 0) ? 'show it after every 4 elements' : ''"
```

for example, inject a span:

```
<span v-if="index % 4 === 0">after 4</span>
```

Comment: but I want to use the index out of the for loop. as you see the code